# Why is this code for processing not displaying any video?

Tags: java, processing

I created this code for my thesis but it doesn't display any video. any clue why? the code is supposed to play a video, connect to the serial port where my Arduino Nano 33 BLE is sending the gestures it detects and based on the gestures play a different video. Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

```
import processing.video.*;
import processing.serial.*;

Serial myPort;
Movie currentVideo;
boolean videoPlaying = false;
String Name;


void setup() {
  size(1080, 1920);
  currentVideo = new Movie(this, "look1,1.mp4");
  Name="look1,1.mp4";
  currentVideo.play();
  videoPlaying = true;

  String portName = Serial.list()[0];
  myPort = new Serial(this, "/dev/tty.usbmodem142401", 9600);
}

void draw() {
  if (videoPlaying && currentVideo.available()) {
    image(currentVideo, 0, 0, width, height);
  }

  if (currentVideo.time() >= currentVideo.duration()) {
    currentVideo.stop();
    while (myPort.available() > 0) {
      String input = myPort.readStringUntil('\n');
      if (input != null) {
        input = input.trim();
        if (input.equals("up")) {
          currentVideo = new Movie(this, "look1,5.mp4");
          Name="look1,5.mp4";
          currentVideo.play();
          videoPlaying = true;
          registerMovieEvent(currentVideo);
          break;
        } else if (input.equals("down")) {
          currentVideo = new Movie(this, "look1,6.mp4");
          Name="look1,6.mp4";
          currentVideo.play();
          videoPlaying = true;
          registerMovieEvent(currentVideo);
          break;
        } else if (input.equals("left")) {
          currentVideo = new Movie(this, "look1,3.mp4");
          Name="look1,3.mp4";
          currentVideo.play();
          videoPlaying = true;
          registerMovieEvent(currentVideo);
          break;
        } else if (input.equals("right")) {
          currentVideo = new Movie(this, "look1,2.mp4");
          Name="look1,2.mp4";
          currentVideo.play();
          videoPlaying = true;
          registerMovieEvent(currentVideo);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (!videoPlaying) {
      currentVideo = new Movie(this, "look1,3.mp4");
      Name="look1,3.mp4";
      currentVideo.play();
      videoPlaying = true;
    }
  }
}

void registerMovieEvent(Movie m) {
  if (currentVideo == m) {
  }
}

void movieEvent(Movie m) {
  if (currentVideo != null && currentVideo.time() >= currentVideo.duration()) {
    currentVideo.stop();
    if (Name=="look1,3.mp4") {
      currentVideo = new Movie(this, "look2,1.mp4");
      Name="look2,1.mp4";
    } else if (Name=="look1,5.mp4" || Name=="look1,6.mp4" || Name=="look1,2.mp4") {
      currentVideo = new Movie(this, "look1,4.mp4");
      Name="look1,4.mp4";
    }
    currentVideo.play();
    videoPlaying = true;
    registerMovieEvent(currentVideo);
  }
}
```

The videos are of course in the data folder and the conncection with my Arduino Nano 33 BLE seems to be working.

Comment: Are you certain that Processing works with BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy)?  Is this for a desktop computer or Android device?  All the code that I have seen for a desktop system is with Bluetooth Classic.  My suggestion would be to start with a very simple example to make sure that your Arduino connection is really working.

Comment: I'm not using bluetooth right now. The Arduino is connected to my computer where processing is playing. I have already tried just sending text through the serial port and it works.

Comment: Are you saying that the default video (shown at startup) doesn't work?  On my system your code showed nothing until I added 'currentVideo.read();' as the first line in the 'movieEvent()' function.

Comment: @apodidae the video is showing now! thank you very much :) however, nothing happens with the gestures

Comment: Usually 'gestures' implies touch screen of some sort.  There was no Arduino code posted.

Comment: the gestures are recognised properly because they are printed correctly on the serial monitor in Arduino IDE so I think the problem is with the processing code

Comment: Then you need to write a very simple Processing app that receives simple byte commands such as 'u','d','l','r'.  That's easier than sending longer strings.  Post the simple Processing code if you still can't get it to work.